# RAM ticking all the time on Linux box

Tags: linux

I have Ubuntu as my dev box and for the last few weeks the RAM has been ticking all the time. I know how to list processes that are using the most memeory using `top` but I was wondering if there is a way to show processes that have accessed the ram the most (say in a 5 sec window)?

Comment: Ticking? Is it BOMB-RAM?

Comment: This would probably be better asked on [unix.se] or [ubuntu.se]

Comment: I'm very curious what you mean with "ticking". Do you mean the RAM modules actually produce an audible ticking noise?

Comment: My hovercraft is full of eels?

Comment: ticking = being used. You know, whenever anything is being written to RAM it ticks

Comment: (Doesn't anyone else think the sound of RAM being accessed sounds like ticking?)

Comment: @Sevenearths: No, because my RAM doesn't make a sound when it's being accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run top

RSS is the use of physical RAM

use the O key press to get the sort selection screen then choose q for the Resident Set Size,
press return to get back to the top display

> (Doesn't anyone else think the sound of RAM being accessed sounds like ticking?)

I for one do not :)